# Permission issues while docker push

Tags: docker, docker-image

I'm trying to push my docker image to google container image registry but get an error which says I do not have the needed permission to perform this operation.

I have already tried gcloud auth configure-docker but it doesn't work for me.

I first build the image using:
docker build -t gcr.io/trynew/hello-world-image:v1 .

Then I'm trying to attach a tag and push it:
docker push gcr.io/trynew/hello-world-image:v1

This is my output :

```
    The push refers to repository [gcr.io/trynew/hello-world-image]

    e62774cdb1c2: Preparing 
    0f6265b750f3: Preparing 
    f82351274ce3: Preparing 
    31a16430afc8: Preparing 
    67298499a3ed: Preparing 
    62d5f39c8fe4: Waiting 
    9f8566ee5135: Waiting 
    unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this
    operation, and you may have invalid credentials. 
    To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: 
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

Comment: did you find any useful information? can you mark valid answer or post any information regarding the actual state of your problem?

Comment: In my case, I was using the snap version of docker.  After installing the normal version (which, right now, is Docker version 19.03.3, build a872fc2f86), the problem went away.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to be able to push images to the private registry you need two things: **API Access Scopes** and **Authenticate your VM with the registry**.

For the **API Access Scopes** (https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-with-google-cloud-platform) we can read in the official documentation:

**For GKE:**

> By default, new Google Kubernetes Engine clusters are created with
>   read-only permissions for Storage buckets. To set the read-write
>   storage scope when creating a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster, use
>   the --scopes option.

**For GCE:**

> By default, a Compute Engine VM has the read-only access scope
>   configured for storage buckets. To push private Docker images, your
>   instance must have read-write storage access scope configured as
>   described in Access scopes.

So first, verify if your GKE cluster or GCE instance actually has the proper scopes set.

The next is to authenticate to the registry:

a) If you are using a Linux based image, you need to use "**gcloud auth configure-docker**" (https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication).

b) For  Container-Optimized OS (COS), the command is “**docker-credential-gcr configure-docker**” (https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/run-container-instance#accessing_private_google_container_registry)

Comment: There could be a case you dont have `docker-credential-gcr` on your machine. Go ahead and install it with `gcloud components install docker-credential-gcr`, reopen cmd (if on windows) and run `docker-credential-gcr configure-docker`.

Answer (score 76):

Google cloud services have specific information how to grant permissions for docker push, this is the first thing you should have a look I think, https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control

After checking that you have sufficient permissions you should proceed with authentication with something like:

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

See more here: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling

Comment: And after you follow all those instructions, you get the same error.  Something is missing from the documentation.

Comment: Just found this tiny note in the docs for gcloud docker credential helper (i.e. command above)... "Note: This command will not work for docker installed via Snap, as the docker snap package does not currently provide an interface for credential helpers."

Answer (score 31):

If you are running `docker` as root (i.e. with `sudo docker`), then make sure to configure the authentication as root. You can run for example:

```
sudo -s
gcloud auth login
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

...that will create (or update) a file under `/root/.docker/config.json`.

(Are there any security implications of `gcloud auth login` as  `root`? Let me know in the comments.)

Comment: This work both windows and Linux

Comment: save my day, didn't even notice this when I use wsl on windows

Comment: I fired the above commands as non-root user instead. It worked well for me.

Answer (score 8):

### Windows / Powershell

I got this error on Windows when I was trying to run `docker push` from a normal powershell window after authenticating in the google cloud shell that had opened when I installed the SDK.

The solution was simple:

**Start a new powershell window to run docker push after running the `gcloud auth configure-docker` command**.

Make sure you've activated the registry too:

```
gcloud services enable containerregistry.googleapis.com
```

Also Google has a tendency to jump to a default account (maybe your personal gmail) which may or may not be the one you want (your business email). Make sure if you're opening any links in a browser that you're in the correct Google account.

I'm not exactly sure what's going on yet because I'm brand new to docker, but something got refreshed when starting a new Powershell instance.

Comment: Thanks Simon, of all the solutions on this page yours was the only one that solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is the only way that worked for me. I found it in a kubernetes/kompose Github issue.

> 1. Remove the `credsStore` key in `~/.docker/config.json`
>
> This will force docker to write the auth into the json when you use `docker login`. You can't untick `Securely store Docker logins in macOS keychain` in the docker desktop any more -- and the current `credStore` is no longer macOS keychain, it's `desktop`.
>
> 2. `gcloud auth login` Auth with gcloud (just to be explicit)
> 3. `gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://eu.gcr.io`
>
> You should see this:
>
> ```
> WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /Users/andrew/.docker/config.json.
> Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
>
> Login Succeeded
> ```

Source: https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose/issues/1043#issuecomment-609019141

Answer (score 5):

First thing, Make sure you covered all points listed in the following official documentation
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
This error occurs mostly due to docker config update, which you can check using command `cat .docker/config.json`

Now update with gcr with following command

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

Answer (score 4):

as noted https://stackoverflow.com/a/59799035/2628337[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59799035/2628337) there appears to be a bug in the Linux version of cloud sdk where authentication fails using the standard authentication method (gcloud auth configure-docker). Instead, create a JSON keyfile per [this](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json-key) and that tends to work.

Answer (score 4):

I still can't get the `gcloud auth configure-docker` helper to work. What did was authenticating with an [access token](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#token), like so

```
gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://HOSTNAME
```

where HOSTNAME is `gcr.io`, `us.gcr.io`, `eu.gcr.io`, or `asia.gcr.io`. (Be sure to include https://, otherwise it won't work).

You can view options for `print-access-token` [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-access-token).

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone else is banging their head against a wall my PIA VPN caused this behavior.

```
"unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication"
```

Turn my VPN off and it works fine. Turn it back on and it breaks again.

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same issue in the Linux environment. So I just set the Docker to run as a non-root user, (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user), and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is as follows: run `gcloud auth login` (the browser will open and allow you to authenticate) then run `gcloud auth configure-docker` and select Y - then redo push. It should work like charm.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens to me when i switch service account which is pointing to different GCP Projects. Even though the service account has permission to push it says it does not have the permission. To resolve this by deleting `config.json` file which is present in `.docker`

Once this is done run the below commands and you should be able to push the image.

`gcloud auth configure-docker`

`gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://HOSTNAME`

Where `HOSTNAME`= `gcr.io` , `asia.gcr.io` etc

Answer (score 0):

In my case `DOCKER_CONFIG` env variable was defined with an invalid value (not pointing to a docker config json).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but for me, the problem was with internal users in my Linux system. I authenticated with **gcloud** my personal Linux user and when pushing, I was doing with **root**. So I had to authenticate my **root** user with gcloud as well:

```
sudo gcloud init
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo Y | sudo gcloud auth configure-docker
```

The above command will be able to initialize the account from a Shell script.

Comment: How is this different from the existing Answers?

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that the

`gcloud auth configure-docker`

will not work with a snap-based docker, as per comment from Danilo Ramires lower on this page.

The aBabin solution then works:

`gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://xxx.io`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had done

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

but this didn't solve my problem.
The issue was that the host `Host1` to which I had to push the docker image was not present in the `.docker/config.json` file.

To solve that, I had to do

```
gcloud auth configure-docker <Host1>
gcloud auth login
```

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling#auth

This solved the problem.