# Unable to push to Google Container Registry - Permission issue

Tags: google-container-registry

I'm having the sample problem as [Vaclav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592243/google-container-registry-permission). I've followed the GCR quick start to the letter which entailed creating a new project (called gcr-project) and copying the code for a Flask (python) app.

After building the docker image, I entered the commands:

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
docker tag quickstart-image gcr.io/gcr-project/quickstart-image:tag1
docker push gcr.io/gcr-project/quickstart-image:tag1
```

The response was:

```
unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

So it would be nice to know if the issue is with the credentials (I'm using cloud SDK OK for other projects) or permissions. The documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control) suggests you need storage-admin rights but the projects already has it, see screen cap [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCtJ8.png)

Would appreciate any tips for trouble shooting this as I was looking for to using the GCR but this problem is a hard stop for me.

**UPDATE:**
I tried the same process with the cloud shell

```
me@cloudshell:~ (gcr-project-XXXXXX)$ docker push gcr.io/gcr-project/quickstart-image:tag1
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/gcr-project/quickstart-image]
4399528b7213: Preparing
1d10b1eeca74: Preparing
75156020d862: Preparing
c5697656a146: Preparing
2a435270de82: Preparing
c35f70b5c25a: Waiting
28e260baaf1b: Waiting
556c5fb0d91b: Waiting

denied: Token exchange failed for project 'gcr-project'. Please enable Google Container Registry API in Cloud Console at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/containerregistry.googleapis.com/overview?project=gcr-project before performing this operation.
me@cloudshell:~ (gcr-project-XXXXXX)$
```

This prompted me to check the API & Services dashboard to confirm the container-registry API was enabled - It is.

**UPDATE 2:**
I'm having these problems on a machine running ubuntu 19.04. Per the comments below I was able to do a push via the cloud shell. So I then went through the same exercise on a MacBook Pro - worked no problems.

So I then uninstalled Cloud SDK [per the doco](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/uninstall-cloud-sdk) having used the standard [linux install instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux) previously. I then re-installed using the [debian-ubuntu install instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu) (version 274.0.1-0)... STILL no go.

When I do a docker pull on the image (because push worked on MBP) I get this error: `Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication`

And when I do a push I get this error: `unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication`

So at this stage, given the success on the MBP and the lack thereof on the linux/ubuntu machine, the problem is constrained to to linux/ubuntu installs.

**UPDATE 3:**
I got on to a separate ubuntu server, did a clean install with `sudo snap install google-cloud-sdk --classic` , did everything else per the docs and still had the exact same problem. So I recon this is a linux google cloud SDK specific problem.

Is there anyone out there Ubuntu land who as been able install and use cloud SDK with GCR recently?????????

Comment: Never used GCR myself, but are you sure that **gcr-project** is not used by someone else already?

Comment: You reference the project-name (gcr-project) in the commands and on the cloud-shell you'll see the unique project-id (gcr-project-XXXXXX) on the cli prompt. I changed the id number to XXXXXX to protect the innocent.

Comment: Shouldn't this ```docker push gcr.io/gcr-project/quickstart-image:tag1``` be ```docker push gcr.io/gcr-project-XXXXXX/quickstart-image:tag1``` then? (same goes for tagging too)

Comment: You're right, I re-read the doco says `docker push [HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]:[TAG]` so I re-did everything in cloud-shell and this time it worked with `docker push gcr.io/gcr-project-264210/quickstart-image:tag1` HOWEVER ...

When I re-do it with PROJECT-ID on my local machine I still get `unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

` ... so something wonky with the set up on my machine.

Comment: According to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication), I think you should use ```gcloud docker``` command instead of using ```docker``` command directly.

Comment: Already tried that and I get the same result. Also, the same doco suggests that you use `gcloud auth configure-docker` as the preferred method - which I am. I'll also point out the same method works fine on macOS per UPDATE2.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to replicate this issue on multiple ubuntu machines. I tried again after the most recent cloud SDK update (276.0.0) but had no luck.

In the end I went with json key file authentincati [described in the docs here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json_key_file) as a work around which worked fine.

Comment: I've also had the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. There seems to be a bug right now.

Comment: Same problem here, Ubuntu 18.04