# Don't have permission to push to GCR - but am owner of the project

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

Pushing to `eu.gcr.io/my-project-name/my-image:tag`, I get:

`unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication`

I have gcloud installed, and when I use `gcloud auth list`, I see the selected account is the owner of the project.

I've run `gcloud auth configure-docker` and my Docker config file contains `gcloud` as credential helpers, accordingly. I've confirmed that docker is using the same config, because if I temporarily empty out the config, `docker push` gives a different error.

I also used:

`docker login -u oauth2accesstoken -p 'token_here' https://eu.gcr.io` after getting an access token via `gcloud auth print-access-token`.

This is a new laptop, and the user was fine to push to the registry previously... I'm quite lost.

Versions:

```
Google Cloud SDK 310.0.0
bq 2.0.60
core 2020.09.11
gsutil 4.53


Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Azure integration  0.1.15
 Version:           19.03.12
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        48a66213fe
 Built:             Mon Jun 22 15:43:18 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.12
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.10
  Git commit:       48a66213fe
  Built:            Mon Jun 22 15:49:27 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem - which happened after the latest Docker Desktop update earlier this week. I disabled "Enable Cloud Experience" in the "Command Line" options in the Desktop Settings window. It then worked ...

Comment: Yup, this was it! Can I ask how you found this answer?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot? I don't see a button to write "Settings" in Docker Desktop.

Answer (score 5):

If somebody else stumbles upon this but has made sure that it really is not an issue with your permissions or Docker Desktop, you might run into the same trap as me. It can happen when you use `sudo` to run docker.
The solution is somewhat hidden in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#gcloud-helper) (at the end of the linked section):

> Note: If you normally run Docker commands on Linux with sudo, Docker
> looks for Artifact Registry credentials in /root/.docker/config.json
> instead of $HOME/.docker/config.json. If you want to use sudo with
> docker commands instead of using the Docker security group, configure
> credentials with sudo gcloud auth configure-docker instead.

Comment: This is incredibly useful, mc51! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this. I spent the day debugging this random "permission denied" issue and found out via this comment, that it somehow fixes the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73637788/permission-denied-on-docker-pull-from-google-cloud-compute/73637789

Answer (score 2):

You must be authenticated to the Container Registry before tagging an image to successfully push the image to the registry.

If you want to push images to a registry you need two things: **API Access Scopes** and **Authenticate your VM with the registry**.

According to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-with-google-cloud-platform)

#### For Compute Engine:

- By default, a Compute Engine VM has the `read-only` access scope configured for storage buckets. To push private Docker images, the VM instance must have the `read-write` storage [access scope](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#integration).

#### For Google Kubernetes Engine:

- By default, a Compute Engine VM has the read-only access scope configured for storage buckets. To push private Docker images, the VM instance must have the read-write storage [access scope](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#integration).

To set the `read-write` storage scope when creating a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster, use the `--scopes` option.

For more information about scopes you can set when creating a new cluster, refer to the documentation for the command [gcloud container clusters create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create).

The first step is to verify if your GKE cluster or GCE instance actually has the proper scopes set.

Then it is necessary to authenticate to the registry:

- If you are using a Linux based image, configure Docker with the following command:

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

You can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication) for more details.

But if you are using  Container-Optimized OS (COS), the command is:

```
docker-credential-gcr configure-docker
```

Please take a look at this other [link](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/run-container-instance#accessing_private_google_container_registry)

Additionally, I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59799035/14004844) on Stackoverflow where it appears to be a bug in the Linux version of Cloud SDK and the authentication fails using the standard authentication method `gcloud auth configure-docker`. And they use the [JSON key file](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json-key) method as a workaround.

Comment: If I may say - this account works fine from another laptop, which suggests the account access level is fine. I've also run the commands as described. I'm also on Windows, not Linux. Can I ask what you mean by "Authenticate your VM with the ]registry" - I'm not on a VM? Is that the same as the "By default, a Compute Engine VM has the read-only access scope" part? Suggesting I'm pushing from a VM?

Comment: I meant to use the command `gcloud auth configure-docker` for the auth, but as you mentioned you are using Windows not linux, so it doesn't apply to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm out on a limb here (not being overly familiar with GCR) but Project Owner may not necessarily contain the required permissions in order to update objects in the underlying storage bucket (eg. storage.objects.create etc). It's possible this could have been removed. You may want to check you have the 'Storage Admin' role on the project/bucket (or Storage Legacy Bucket Owner).