# Permission denied on docker pull from Google Cloud Compute

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

So I set up a minimal Google Cloud Compute instance with terraform and want to use a docker image on it. The desired image is pushed to an artifact repository in the same project.

## Error

The issue is that whatever I do, when trying to pull with the pull command specified in the artifact repo, I get:

```
sudo docker pull europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/[project]/[repo]/[image]:latest
Error response from daemon: 
Head "https://europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/v2/[project]/[repo]/api/manifests/latest": denied: 
Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/[project]/locations/europe-west3/repositories/[repo]" (or it may not exist)
```

## Debugging attempts

What I've tried:

- The default service account [should have access](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#default) without any additional setup. To debug and make sure nothing goes wrong, I tried creating a service account with the necessary role myself.
- Tried to debug access with the policy troubleshooting tool, access should be possible
- Made sure to enable docker auth with `gcloud auth configure-docker europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev` and debugged the used account with `gcloud auth list`.
- Tried the pull command on my local machine, works flawlessly
- Tried to access the repo via `gcloud artifacts docker images list [repo]`, works fine as well
- Tried to run `gcloud init`
- Tried pulling images from the official docker repo, also works flawlessly

## Terraform code for reference

```
#
# INSTANCE
#
resource "google_compute_instance" "mono" {
  name = "mono"
  machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
  allow_stopping_for_update = true  # allows hard updating

  service_account {
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-11"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"
    access_config {

    }
  }
}


#
# REPO
#
resource "google_artifact_registry_repository" "repo" {
  location      = var.location
  repository_id = var.project_name
  format        = "DOCKER"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

After wasting too many hours on this, I found that after adding my user to the docker group and thus running docker without `sudo`, it suddenly works.

So as laid out here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
# exit and login again via ssh
```

## Explanation

As per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#gcloud-helper):

> Note: If you normally run Docker commands on Linux with sudo, Docker looks for Artifact Registry credentials in /root/.docker/config.json instead of $HOME/.docker/config.json. If you want to use sudo with docker commands instead of using the Docker security group, configure credentials with sudo gcloud auth configure-docker instead.

So if you use docker with sudo, you also need to run

```
sudo gcloud auth configure-docker
```

I thought I had tried this, but it is what it is...

Comment: Your answer is partially correct. If you initialized the CLI (gcloud), then the CLI credentials are preferred instead of the attached service account. VM's have an access scope setting, the default configuration limits the permissions assigned to the service account. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam In summary you had one authorization problem (service account permissions) and replaced that with a new problem (gcloud init).

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the answer. So what exactly happened? I think I still don't get it. What was the service account permission problem (was set to cloud platform), see terraform, and how did I replace it? I never used my personal credentials anywhere within the machine. Feel free to create an answer if you care to elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: On linux, if you don't want to logout and login, you can run the command " newgrp docker " as specified in the "Post-installation steps for Linux", to activate the changes to groups.